# python function returning "22, 'Invalid argument'" when calling from jenkins framework

Tags: python, shell, jenkins

I am using *jenkins* framework to run python script in unix shell but its giving error like :

> **CRITICAL - (22, 'Invalid argument')**

Same script works fine when execute manually from shell.

Here is my code:

**FUNCTION 1:**

```
def check_diskspace(ip,usr):

    l = []
    cmds='ssh %s@%s'%(usr,ip)
    child1=pexpect.spawn(cmds)
    for i in range(1,5):
       child1.sendline("df -h /d/oss/global | awk '{if (NR>2) {print}}' | awk -F ' ' '{print $" + str(i) + "}'")
        child1.expect(prompt)
        l.append(child1.before.strip(cmds).split('\n')[1])
   return l
```

**FUNCTION 2**

```
def TC1():

    logger.info("Start TC1")
    l = check_diskspace(nfsip,username)
    Totalspace = l[0].strip('\r')
    print "Totalspace=",Totalspace

if('global_100fill' == sys.argv[1]):
        TC1()
```

**Note**: I am calling script from jenkins as:

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Stress_test/Stress_framework/usecase.py global_100fill
```

Comment: I investigated the code further and found that interact() function of python pexpect module is giving the problem.  after interact() statement no other statement get execute in that function. I don't know why this is giving problem only while running using jenkins server.